# Run "dotnet ef migrations script" from the last migration

Tags: azure-devops, entity-framework-core

In Azure DevOps I have a build task with the following command:

```
dotnet ef migrations script --output path/migrations-script.sql --idempotent
```

In my release pipeline I run the generated script.

The issue I've got is that the above command runs from the first migration. I know I can specify a `from` argument for this command, but you have to specify the name of migration. Is there any way to generate the script from the last migration without specifying its name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to generate the script from the last migration
>   without specifying its name?

As I know, it's necessary for us to specify the name when we try to generate script from last migration, unless we have only one migration.

See [the details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-migrations-script) about `dotnet ef migrations script`:

**Arguments:**

`From`: *The starting migration. Migrations may be identified by name or by ID. The number 0 is a special case that means before the first migration. Defaults to 0.*

`To`: *The ending migration. Defaults to the last migration.*

So if we have more than one migrations, we have to specify `From` with the start migration we want. This behavior is **by design**. Check [this post](https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/42586235/how-to-get-the-database-update-script-from-the-last-migration-), to generate script from last migration we should use format like:

`dotnet ef migrations script -from (MigrationYouWant-1) -to MigrationYouWant`

So I'm afraid there's no other way to do this in Devops pipeline or local machine, we have to specify the command with name. Hope my answer can help to clarify something for you:)